# Linking to dynamic routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

When I use the `next/link` component to link my pages together, I ended up having to specify both the "server side" URL and the queryparam-eterized URL.

An example could be a dynamic `/post/:id` route that is served by the `pages/post.js` file:

```
<Link href="/post?id=2" as="/post/2"><a>Go to post number 2</a></Link>
```

Is there a different way to do this? It's cumbersome to remember to do this everywhere I want to have a dynamic route.

Comment: It looks like [you don't have to specify both of them if you don't want to](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/b492e6703de62e1b4a63957350108ce8db6eeb68/lib/link.js#L141-L145).

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK I think that code relates to passing on the `href` tag to the immediate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` is always necessary as it point to the `page` that will take care of rendering the content. However the `as` prop is optional, it's only used to "prettify" the URL shown to the user.

Imagine you land on a site and you see www.mysite.com/post?id=121, looks uglier than just /post/2.

This is still cumbersome, hence there are a few nice libraries that make this easier, the most popular AFAIK is https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-routes, this package makes your life easier when using `Link`, however you need to write down your own routes.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I kind of landed on the same conclusion. Thanks for the tip on `next-routes` though - hadn't spotted that one yet.