# Next.js Link "as" decorator stopped working for dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I have a dynamic route:

```
test/[id].js
```

When user clicks on a link pointing to `/test/1` Next.js ends up rendering the proper page as intended.

The funny business starts when I want to have `/test/1` url masked with anything else.

`<Link href="/test/1" as="/any/thing/here">`

As far as I understand the above code should:

- move user to test/1 and render test/[id].js,
- hide the domain.com/test/1 url behind domain.com/any/thing/here.

What happens is it does not point to test/[id].js at all, just returns a 404.

Sandbox link with broken code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-silence-z62s1?file=/pages/index.js

What am I doing wrong here? I have a really long and complex urls with lots of slashes I have to use with Next.js dynamic routing, and I don't see any other solution than using "as"... I'm pretty much sure I used to use it a few years back and it just worked! Seems like it worked for this guy as well: [Linking to dynamic routes in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640351/linking-to-dynamic-routes-in-next-js)

If Next.js changed something then how I recreate this functionality easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to write `href` like that:

```
      <Link
        href="/test/[id]?id=1"
        // Or like that
        href={{
          pathname: '/test/[id]',
          query: { id: '1' }
        }}
        as="/any/thing/here"
      >
        <a>Link to test/1 - 'as' decorator is broken?</a>
      </Link>
```

I am not sure why it works like that, but I saw it somewhere some time ago and I use it like that since then. I think there is no information about it in the docs.

And be sure that `/any/thing/here` page actually exists too, because otherwise if user refresh browser after client side navigation there will be 404 anyway.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. It's really counterintuitive for it to work like this. By the way any idea how I can handle the `/any/thing/here` pages being there? In my case the url is like `category/subcategory/year/month/day/some-title`, no way to make it work with files... How do I serve proper page after someone does refresh on URL like this one?

Comment: Why not? Just make that page `[category]/[subcategory]/[year]/[month]/[day]/[some-title]/index.js`, that way you are going to have `query` with all this slugs. Totally possible in Next!

Comment: I understand your point but this won't scale. I have over 200 000 entries for ~150 000 different dates. It's impossible to create that many files and totally impossible to maintain those. That's why I'm wondering how to handle this in some sane way. Possibly some redirect on the server side? I just want one file to serve all those 200 000 entries, but under different urls. The "real" urls won't do as they're hashes and impossible to remember & ugly.

Comment: You don't need to create 200 000 files, it is one dynamic file for all your entries. You probably need to reread this part of the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: For some reason, when I use this I can't retrieve query parameters in my client component using - useSearchParams(). Any idea to make this work?

Comment: Seems like this is changed again in nextjs using the /app router, I can't currently get it to work. Do you happen to know how the "as" prop works with the /app router?

Answer (score 1):

The **Link** component with the as prop to create a "pretty" URL and pass a hidden ID as a query parameter. This way, the ID will be hidden in the visible URL while still being accessible within your Next.js components.

```
import Link from 'next/link';

const MyPage = () => {
  // Your hidden ID that you want to pass
  const hiddenId = 123;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      {/* Use Link to create a pretty URL with the hidden ID */}
      <Link href={`/my-page?id=${hiddenId}`} as="/my-page">
        <a>Go to My Page</a>
      </Link>
      {/* Your page content here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: Well this is not working as expected in your suggestion in the App router